# I want output None instead of 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    first, second = 0,0
    for n in numbers:
        if n > first:
            first, second = n, first
        elif first > n > second:
            second = n
    return second
print(second_largest([2,2,2]))
```

I want to output by None not 0 if there is no second largest number and also if there is empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the return line to `return second or None`.

Answer (score 0):

A little tweak in return statement will do. Check out the below code:

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    first, second = 0,0
    for n in numbers:
        if n > first:
            first, second = n, first
        elif first > n > second:
            second = n
    return None if second ==0 else second
print(second_largest([2,2,2]))
```

Comment: `0` is falsy - so `return second or None` if shorter.